# =Query Returning A cells when B cells has current or future date

Tags: google-sheets

I want to return text from cells in column A when column B contains current or future date.

Column B has set the data validation to date.

I'm able to make it work for today's date with this code, but I cannot do it for today's and future date.
=QUERY(A9:B,"SELECT A WHERE B = date'"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' ",0)

How could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert:

```
 or B > date'"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
```

should work.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you.

Can I add a default text that will be shown when none of the cells has the current or future date? At the moment it shows 'N/A' and an error label :(

Comment: Thanks for suggesting IFERROR. This is what I was looking for.